# How to calculate the current row with the next one?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

In Spark-Sql version 1.6, using `DataFrame`s, is there a way to calculate, for a specific column, the sum of the current row and the next one, for every row?

For example, if I have a table with one column, like so

```
Age
12
23
31
67
```

I'd like the following output

```
Sum
35
54
98
```

The last row is dropped because it has no "next row" to be added to.

Right now I am doing it by ranking the table and joining it with itself, where the `rank` is equals to `rank+1`.

Is there a better way to do this?
Can this be done with a `Window` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes definitely you can do with `Window` function by using `rowsBetween` function. I have used `person` column for `grouping` purpose in my following example.

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val dataframe = Seq(
  ("A",12),
  ("A",23),
  ("A",31),
  ("A",67)
).toDF("person", "Age")

val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("person").orderBy("Age").rowsBetween(0, 1)
val newDF = dataframe.withColumn("sum", sum(dataframe("Age")) over(windowSpec))
  newDF.filter(!(newDF("Age") === newDF("sum"))).show
```

Comment: Use `Window.currentRow` instead

Comment: Thanks. Could you please also look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44392754/416300)?