# How to divide the value of current row with the following one?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

In Spark-Sql version 1.6, using `DataFrame`s, is there a way to calculate, for a specific column, the fraction of dividing current row and the next one, for every row?

For example, if I have a table with one column, like so

```
Age
100
50
20
4
```

I'd like the following output

```
Franction
2
2.5
5
```

The last row is dropped because it has no "next row" to be added to.

Right now I am doing it by ranking the table and joining it with itself, where the `rank` is equals to `rank+1`.

Is there a better way to do this?
Can this be done with a `Window` function?

Comment: Yes. That's the "job" for window aggregate functions. Did you use `/`?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski, I couldn't find `/` or anything similar in `functions`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Window` function should do only partial tricks. Other partial trick can be done by defining a `udf` function

```
def div = udf((age: Double, lag: Double) => lag/age)
```

First we need to find the `lag` using `Window` function and then pass that `lag` and `age` in `udf` function to find the `div` 
    import sqlContext.implicits._
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

```
val dataframe = Seq(
  ("A",100),
  ("A",50),
  ("A",20),
  ("A",4)
).toDF("person", "Age")

val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("person").orderBy(col("Age").desc)
val newDF = dataframe.withColumn("lag", lag(dataframe("Age"), 1) over(windowSpec))
```

And finally cal the udf function

```
newDF.filter(newDF("lag").isNotNull).withColumn("div", div(newDF("Age"), newDF("lag"))).drop("Age", "lag").show
```

Final output would be

```
+------+---+
|person|div|
+------+---+
|     A|2.0|
|     A|2.5|
|     A|5.0|
+------+---+
```

**Edited**
As @Jacek has suggested a better solution to use `.na.drop` instead of `.filter(newDF("lag").isNotNull)` and use `/` operator , so we don't even need to call the `udf` function

```
newDF.na.drop.withColumn("div", newDF("lag")/newDF("Age")).drop("Age", "lag").show
```

Comment: Thanks. In light of your answer, I composed the following (No UDF): `dataframe.select($"person", $"Age"/ (lead("Age", 1) over windowSpec) as "div").na.drop.show`